# jena typed literals & language annotations - how to ommit it when exporting?

Tags: java, scala, rdf, jena, n-triples

i'm reading RDF documents from an `InputStream`, as follows (scala syntax):

```
def foo(rdfData: InputStream, dialect: String = null) = {
  require(List("RDF/XML", "N-TRIPLE", "TURTLE", "TTL", "N3", "RDF/XML-ABBREV").contains(dialect) || dialect == null)
  val model: Model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel
  model.read(rdfData, null, dialect)
  doSomethingWithTriplesIterator(model.listStatements())
}
```

now, some triples has typed literals, so i do something like:

```
val it = model.listStatements()
it.next.getObject.toString
```

i get (sometimes) something like: `"13"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>` or `"Hello world"@en_US` when i'm only intrested at the value as strings, i.e. `13` & `Hello world` in the given example.

is there a way to get the "naked" values staight out of jena's statements? if so, how?
thanks.

**EDIT:**

trying *AndyS* solution, using a triple taken from [yago](http://yago-knowledge.org), i got:

```
scala> val model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel
model: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model = <ModelCom   {} | >

scala> val is = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream("""<http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Mount_Cramer> <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/hasLatitude> "44.01102^^http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/degrees" .""".getBytes("UTF-8"))
is: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream = java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@2b3c4f10

scala> model.read(is, null, "N-TRIPLE")
res0: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model = <ModelCom   {http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Mount_Cramer @http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/hasLatitude "44.01102^^http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/degrees"} |  [http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Mount_Cramer, http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/hasLatitude, "44.01102^^http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/degrees"]>

scala> val it = model.listStatements
it: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator = com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.StmtIteratorImpl@55ef662c

scala> val stmt = it.next
stmt: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement = [http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Mount_Cramer, http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/hasLatitude, "44.01102^^http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/degrees"]

scala> val obj = stmt.getObject
obj: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode = 44.01102^^http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/degrees

scala> val ltrl = obj.asLiteral
ltrl: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal = 44.01102^^http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/degrees

scala> ltrl.getLexicalForm
res1: String = 44.01102^^http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/degrees
```

so as you see, i'm not getting the desired output. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The RDF string that you parsed isn't right.  It has a triple pattern `<...Mount_Cramer> <../hasLatitude> "44.01102^^http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/degrees"`, but that should be `<...Mount_Cramer> <../hasLatitude> "44.01102"^^<http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/degrees>`.  The syntax is `"literal-form"^^<datatype-IRI>`, not `"literal-form^^datatype-IRI"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the [lexical form](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal).  See [Literal.getLexicalForm](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Literal.html#getLexicalForm%28%29).

Comment: I tried it, and as you can see in the updated question, clearly, i did something wrong... so, what am i missing here?

Comment: @giladhoch The code as shown in the update to your question is right, but your RDF data string is not.  (See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904412/jena-typed-literals-language-annotations-how-to-ommit-it-when-exporting#comment29621777_19904412) on the question.)